# Why $().prop() will not set attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why `.prop` will not set the attribute value in the example? Bootstrap 3.1.1 and jQuery 2.1 are used.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
    </label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('label').click
(
    function()
    {
        // Does not set attribute
        $(this).prop('foo','bar');
    }
);
```

[Live demo](http://www.bootply.com/c5mNUZTJjc)

Comment: Code has to go in the question. Your question cannot depend on 3rd party links to be meaningfully answered.

Comment: I added the code from the link to the question, not sure if edits are meant to do that though

Comment: How the hell is this off-topic?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak `.prop` does not work for some reason.

Comment: You are trying to disable a label, not the input element. Use .find() to get the input element. Reason why this question was closed was because it didn't contain any code just a link to your website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr have a look into it.

Comment: The first `prop` line should be: `$(this).attr('disabled',false); // not 'disabled'`

Comment: @Anton now question is improved.

Comment: @عثمانغني I've already voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @Anton I am not disabling anything. I just want an HTML attribute to be added to an HTML element using jQuery. An attribute is not added for some reason.

Comment: @Kolyunya "I am not disabling anything. I just want an HTML **attribute** to be added to an HTML element using jQuery. An **attribute** is not added for some reason." ... use .attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) not [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) like,

```
$('label').click(function(){
    // Use attr as disabled is not a property of a label
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

**disabled is not a property of a label**, so it will not work on `label`, as your tried.
And if you want to add `disabled` as an attribute then you need to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/D9P9f/)

Comment: OP already said his aim is to add a attribute to the element. He just used disabled as an example

Answer (score 0):

`labels` do not have a disable property inherently built in. You will need to add a class to disable them yourself.

Something like:

```
.disabled {
   background-color: #428bca;
}
```

And to add the class to your element:

```
$(this).addClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i thing you are confused between attr and prop,
both are different in many cases this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) will solve your problem